# Selectable Linq queries

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a form with some checkboxes and textboxs, what I want to do:
when user selects a checkbox and write some text, the linq query must executes and search only for selected checkboxes.

For example:

[My form http://upload7.ir/images/54647543164083765376.jpg](http://upload7.ir/images/54647543164083765376.jpg)

If user checks lastname and tell and inputs the data in textboxes, the query retrieves only the selected, and if user checks average too, the query also goes for that and returns 3 join for example.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

LINQ queries are lazy and are not executed until asked for results, so you can do following:

```
var source = GetSourceCollection();
var query = source;

if(FirstNameCheckbox.Checked)
    query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(FirstNameTextBox);

if(LirstNameCheckbox.Checked)
    query = query.Where(x => x.LirstName.Contains(LirstNameTextBox);

// (...)

// execution is right here, when ToList is called
var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I've only done that for old EF but unless things have changed that might need some casting between IQueryable and IObjectQueryable and it might need to rebuild its query plan (taking seconds!) for each new paramterised permutation.